# Slope of the tangent line

Tags: calculus

Find the slope of the tangent line $(-\frac{7}{2} , 0)$ for $f(x)= \ln\frac{7(x+3)}{x}$.

I've tried taking the derivative of the equation and then setting it equal to one and solving for $x$.

Comment: Is $(-\frac72,0)$ even on the graph of $f$?

Comment: ...and what happened with the derivative?! But, of course, Karl's question is even more basic.

Comment: Oh, the whole fraction is the argument to $\ln$. I would like confirmation from the OP that this is the intended expression: $$\ln\left(\frac{7(x+3)}x\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\log(f(x))=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

$$\log\left(\frac{7(x+3)}x\right)=\log 7+\log(x+3)-\log x\;\;\ldots\ldots$$